# Accordion not working in Foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to format an accordion in Foundation (Version 5.5.0), but it's just display the titles of each section without any way of getting to the content below. What am I doing wrong? My html is below:

**Html**

```
<div class="section-container accordion" data-section="accordion">
    <section class="active">
        <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section 1</a>
        </p>
        <div class="content" data-section-content>
            <p>Content of section 1.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Section 2</a>
        </p>
        <div class="content" data-section-content>
            <p>Content of section 2.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).foundation();
```

**[Example](http://flickspedia.com/)**

Comment: You need to explain your problem. What you mean?

Comment: Did you use doctype declaration?

Comment: @NaeemShaikh  i am not getting the out put in desired format. what i get is simply 4 lines,"Section 1

Content of section 1.

Section 2

Content of section 2."

Comment: To me, it looks like he/she is trying to use Foundation's accordion. If that's the case, check whether Foundation's JavaScript is properly inserted and started ($(document).foundation();)...

Comment: yes.. there are four lines?

Comment: @BhojendraSah yes i did. i am not getting the out put in desired format. what i get is simply 4 lines,"Section 1 Content of section 1. Section 2 Content of section 2.". The output was suppose to show two tabs section 1 and section 2, and clicking on them will show this is section1/2.

Comment: @empiric i am not getting the output in the desired format, the o/p was supposed to show 2 tabs, what i get is 4 lines showing the normal text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took my a while to figure it out but I get the example to work:

The [Section](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/components/section.html)-Example you posted seems to be only working with Foundation on Version 4.x.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xfuj4ck7/) example. **(Note the external resources I use)**

In Version > 4 of Foundation there is a [accordion](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html)-functionality:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="accordion" data-accordion>
  <li class="accordion-navigation">
      <a href="#panel1a">Accordion 1</a>
       <div id="panel1a" class="content active">...</div>
  </li>
//and so on   
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0L9x8sno/)**

P.S. I used [this](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/foundation) site for getting the different versions of foundation

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="section-container accordion">
  <p class="title">
    <a href="#">Section 1</a>
  </p>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Content of section 1.
    </p>
  </div>
  <p class="title">
    <a href="#">Section 2</a>
  </p>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Content of section 2.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should really be carefull with formatting.

Comment: Then you JavaScript is not linked well, or the browser cannot find it. Tri clicking right on the page -> Inspect Element, then you will se what`s wrong.